# Где можно бесплатно хранить изображения чтобы к ним был доступ по ссылке?

Tags: android, изображения, access, service, share

Делаю android приложение с большим количеством изображений. Решил что лучше всего их подгружать из интернета т.к. они будут занимать большое количество памяти. В приложении я просто указываю ссылку на изображение и оно загружается. Пытался залить их в сервисы google но там нужна авторизация. В итоге пока создал альбом на сайте vkontakte от туда и загружаю. Есть ли специальные сервисы для размещения там фотографии и загрузки без авторизации?

Comment: Доброе утро =) Попробуйте облачное хранилище **Mega**, так 50гб бесплатно дают! Можно такую галерею забабахать

Comment: Есть большое количество [бесплатных хостингов изображений](https://habrahabr.ru/post/89162/) без авторизации. Еще больше в google по запросу "бесплатный хостинг изображений"

Comment: `лучше всего их подгружать из интернета т.к. они будут занимать большое количество памяти` -- весьма странное решение. А если интернета не будет?

Comment: Если интернета не будет значит картинки загружаться не будут, все просто)

Answer (score 1):

Залейте картинки на [Imgur](https://imgur.com) и грузите иx через библиотеку [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Скачать одной строкой

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```